# Bootstrap 5 responsive ordering with column inside column

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Is it possible to rearrange this layout (md+ devices)...

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="col-8 bg-warning">
      <div>first div</div>
      <div>second div</div>
      <div>third div</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 bg-info">
      other content
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

...to this on xs, sm devices?

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="col-12 bg-warning">
      <div>first div</div>
      <div class="bg-info">
        other content
      </div>
      <div>second div</div>
      <div>third div</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here, the blue column is moved INSIDE the yellow column.

I understand there are `.order` classes, but I've only seen them used for moving one column before another.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly via CSS, but you can use a trick with display properties.

Anyways, remember that bootstrap is a mobile first framework, so you must think in "how can I rearrange this mobile layout, into md screens", the principal layout is mobile, then try to transform the layout to larger screens. Today more than 70% of internet browsing is via smartphones.

Here is the code with Bootstrap 5! :D

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8 bg-warning">
      <div>first div</div>
      <div class="bg-info d-md-none">
        other content
      </div>
      <div>second div</div>
      <div>third div</div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-none d-md-flex col-md-3 bg-info">
      other content
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below:

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="d-lg-flex d-none">
    <div class="col-8 bg-warning">
      <div>first div</div>
      <div>second div</div>
      <div>third div</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 bg-info">
      other content
    </div>
  </div>
   
  <div class="d-lg-none d-flex">
    <div class="col-12 bg-warning">
      <div>first div</div>
      <div class="bg-info">
        other content
      </div>
      <div>second div</div>
      <div>third div</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Explanation: the top code only shows on large screens and hides in small screens, and the bottom code only shows on small screens and hides in large screens.

Comment: I would not recommend to clone the entire section, it is better to duplicate only needed elements to maintain the tree node as small as posible